# Get COUNT for each ID and ID itself in table - mysql

Tags: mysql

I wanted to know how often an invoiceID appears among the invoiceLines that this invoice has. SO for example

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ invoiceID+ COUNT(invoiceLines)+
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1        + 10                 +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 2        + 17                 +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 3        + 5                  +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

etc.

My current query looks like this:

```
select DISTINCT invoice.invoiceID, COUNT(invoiceLine.invoiceLineID) 
from invoice join invoiceLine on invoiceLine.fk_invoiceID = 
invoice.invoiceID;
```

Though this won't work, as I'm selecting a none aggregated value and an aggregated value. Hence the error message:

```
In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'wms_new.invoice.invoiceID'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Does anybody know how to pull off something like this without disabling "sql_mode=only_fill_group_by"

Comment: remove `DISTINCT` and add `GROUP BY invoice.invoiceID` to the end of your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requirement can actually be answered entirely by the invoice lines table. You don't need the join to invoice:

```
select fk_invoiceID, COUNT(*) 
from invoiceLine 
group by fk_invoiceID
```

In your current MySQL mode every column in the select list that is NOT an aggregating function (count, min, max, sum, avg etc) must appear in the group by also

The scenario where you would use DISTINCT are quite narrow; seek to avoid using it. It's not required in a grouping query because by their very nature they produce outputs where rows are a unique set of values

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I did notice that too after seeing Nicks comment. I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as I can.